# How to filter a PrintStream

Tags: java, irc, chatbot

Im trying to code a basic irc chatbot using [PircBotX](https://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/). I want to output the chat to a text file and couldn't find a way to do so. I am coding my own and can output the console to a file with lines that look something like this:

13:12:09.110 [botPool0-bot0] INFO  org.pircbotx.InputParser - :jdbener!jdbener@jdbener.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #irish_00 :yay

I would like it to write it to the file like this:

13:12 < Twitch> Jdbener: yay

Here is the code i have for the writer file:

```
public class writer extends OutputStream {
public void write(int b) throws IOException {
     String Output = String.valueOf((char)b);
     FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output-dirty.txt", true);
     writer.append(Output);
     writer.close();
     testbot.stringB.append(Output);
 }
 }
```

If you need anything else let me know and I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: what exactly is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the questions is how to make this :

```
13:12:09.110 [botPool0-bot0] INFO org.pircbotx.InputParser - :jdbener!jdbener@jdbener.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #irish_00 :yay
```

look like this:

```
13:12 < Twitch> Jdbener: yay
```

the you can do something like this:

```
 String a = "13:12:09.110 [botPool0-bot0] INFO org.pircbotx.InputParser - :jdbener!jdbener@jdbener.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #irish_00 :yay";

 String[] b = a.split(":");

 String c =   b[0] + ":" + 
              b[1] + 
              "<Twitch>" +
              b[3].split("!")[0].replace(b[3].split("!")[0].charAt(0), Character.toUpperCase(b[3].split("!")[0].charAt(0))) + 
              ": " +
              b[b.length - 1];
```

Testing with `System.out.println(c);` will output: `13:12<Twitch>Jdbener: yay`

Of course i am assuming there is some consistency with the original `String`. If the answer doesn't work very well then paste some more example input `Strings` and will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you, your response was really help full in figuring out how filter my stream.